# How do I make a macro for a struct generate a function method matching on the struct?

Tags: macros, julia

Pardon any confused terminology in the title, but imagine I want to have a little macro to mark structs I create as usable for some nefarious purpose. I write this little module:

```
module Usable

export @usable, isusable

isusable(::Type{T}) where T = false

macro usable(expr::Expr)
    name = expr.args[2]

    return quote
        $expr
        
        Usable.isusable(::Type{$name}) = true     # This in't working
    end
end

end
```

However, trying to use my macro

```
julia> include("Usable.jl")
Main.Usable

julia> using Main.Usable

julia> @usable struct Foo
           bar::String
       end
```

results in

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: Foo not defined
```

The struct was evidently defined just fine

```
julia> Foo("soup")
Foo("soup")
```

so it would seem the definition is required earlier than I expect. I am obviously missing something, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always have a look at the output of your macros:

```
julia> @macroexpand @usable struct Foo
                  bar::String
              end
quote
    #= REPL[1]:11 =#
    struct Foo
        #= REPL[4]:2 =#
        bar::Main.Usable.String
    end
    #= REPL[1]:13 =#
    (Main.Usable.Usable).isusable(::Main.Usable.Type{Main.Usable.Foo}) = begin
            #= REPL[1]:13 =#
            true
        end
end
```

The problem is that the macro output is expanded within the module it has been defined, which messes up what the names mean.  In this case, we want `Foo` to refer to the namespace where it was defined, though:

```
quote
    #= REPL[1]:11 =#
    struct Foo
        #= REPL[10]:2 =#
        bar::String
    end
    #= REPL[1]:13 =#
    Usable.isusable(::Type{Foo}) = begin
            #= REPL[1]:13 =#
            true
        end
end
```

It's actually simple to get that -- just escape the output:

```
macro usable(expr::Expr)
   name = expr.args[2]

   return esc(quote
       $expr
       $Usable.isusable(::Type{$name}) = true
   end)
end
```

But do read the macro documentation again.  `esc` is quite intricate, and you don't want to blindly apply it to everything you write.

The other thing (and I hope to get this right) is to splice in the module itself -- `$Usable` -- instead of referring to it by name.  Otherwise you might have a problem if you rename the module name outside.

Comment: Works like a charm! I tried escaping the name and using QuoteNode, but it never occurred to me to escape the entire return expression.

Comment: There are some who opine that macros should be escaped by default, with hygiene being opt-in. I prefer hygiene by default, but they have a point, as we see here.

Answer (score 1):

In the described scenario almost always you should use Julia's powerful type system and multiple dispatch mechanism not a macro. (Perhaps you have a good reason to do so but this is information for others.)
The pattern is to simply define the desired behavior through an abstract type that is later inherited by a custom `struct`.

One example is here for adding a `Comparable` behavior to composite `struct`s.

```
abstract type Comparable end

import Base.==
==(a::T, b::T) where T <: Comparable =
    getfield.(Ref(a),fieldnames(T)) == getfield.(Ref(b),fieldnames(T))
```

And now using:

```
julia> struct MyStruct <: Comparable 
    f::Vector{String}  
end;

julia> MyStruct(["hello"]) == MyStruct(["hello"])
true
```

Comment: Very well for the non-nefarious cases. We might also want to mention traits here, in case the OP really would need multiple inheritance.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately MI is not available in Julia. Maybe Julia 2.0.